# How do i implement nested NSSplitView like below?

Tags: cocoa, autolayout, xamarin.mac, nssplitview

I am trying to implement this with autolayout

[image]

after running my application, second splitview is showing like this :(

[image]

Can anyone please guide me to solve this

Comment: Please check this : https://github.com/steipete/PSStackedView

Comment: @Mayur Thanks for your response, i solved this issue :).I missed to set constraints

Comment: ohh thats great. Btw you can add in answer how you resolved your issue. that will help others for reference.